# Checking the integrity of NFS files with tripwire

Tags: nfs, tripwire

I installed tripwire for integrity checker. I want tripwire to checks some NFS mounted folders on the network, but it says:

```
**The object: "/mnt/nfs/etc" is on a different file system...ignoring.
The object: "/mnt/nfs/home" is on a different file system...ignoring.**
```

How can I fix this skipping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your config

```
 CROSSFILESYSTEMS=true
```

That should let it follow NFS mounts.  (At least in the opensource version).

Answer (score 0):

thanks, it worked. it's no available on the internet.
do you have any idea about this non-existence directories :

```
### Warning: File system error.
### Filename: /bin/pgawk
### No such file or directory
### Continuing...
### Warning: File system error.
### Filename: /bin/zsh
### No such file or directory
### Continuing...
### Warning: File system error.
### Filename: /bin/ksh
### No such file or directory
### Continuing...
### Warning: File system error.
### Filename: /bin/tcsh
### No such file or directory
### Continuing...
### Warning: File system error.
### Filename: /dev/cua0
### No such file or directory
### Continuing...
### Warning: File system error.
### Filename: /dev/initctl
### No such file or directory
### Continuing...
```

i comment it in on policy config but nothing changed.